# Group by for time series - where dates matter

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, time-series

I have the following information

| project | stage | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 33 | New | 3-sep-2022 |
| 33 | New | 10-sep-2022 |
| 33 | Preparation | 11-sep-2022 |
| 33 | Preparation | 21-sep-2022 |
| 33 | Preparation | 23-sep-2022 |
| 33 | New | 24-sep-2022 |
| 33 | New | 28-sep-2022 |

I want to get the information of the beginning and end of each stage of the project, so I would like this as an output:

| project | stage | begin_stage | end_stage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 33 | New | 3-sep-2022 | 10-sep-2022 |
| 33 | Preparation | 11-sep-2022 | 23-sep-2022 |
| 33 | New | 24-sep-2022 | 28-sep-2022 |

It is important to note that dates matter, so I want to have New twice because the project went back to new on the 24 of September.

I tried the following:

```
min_df = df.groupby(['project', 'stage'], as_index=False)['date'].agg('min')
max_df = df.groupby(['project', 'stage'], as_index=False)['date'].agg('max')

df = pd.merge(min_df, max_df, how='left', on=['project', 'stage'])
df.rename(columns={'date_x': 'begin_state', 'date_y': 'end_state'}, inplace=True)
```

However, this is grouping New in only one group and is giving me beging date 3-sep and end stage 28-sep, which is wrong. So the output that I am getting with my code is:

| project | stage | begin_stage | end_stage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 33 | New | 3-sep-2022 | 28-sep-2022 |
| 33 | Preparation | 11-sep-2022 | 23-sep-2022 |

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

group = df['stage'].ne(df['stage'].shift()).cumsum()

out = (df
   .groupby(['project', 'stage', group], sort=False)
   .agg(**{'begin_stage': ('date', 'min'), 'end_stage': ('date', 'max')})
   .droplevel(-1)
   .apply(lambda s: s.dt.strftime('%-d-%b-%Y').str.lower())
   .reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
   project        stage  begin_stage    end_stage
0       33          New   3-sep-2022  10-sep-2022
1       33  Preparation  11-sep-2022  23-sep-2022
2       33          New  24-sep-2022  28-sep-2022
```